# Showing ajax loader image in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Using Rails 3.2. This is a simple Ajax loading that I coded:

```
# places/revisions.html.erb
<a href="<%= version_path(version) %>" class="diff">View changes</a>

<div id="version"><!-- #version used for ajax -->
  Click "View changes" to see the diff.
</div>

<% content_for :javascript_onload do %>
  $('a.diff').attr('data-remote', 'true');
<% end %>

# versions_controller.rb
class VersionsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @version = Version.find(params[:id])
  end
end

# versions/show.js.erb
$('#version').html('<%= escape_javascript render :partial => "versions/version", :locals => {:version => @version} %>');
```

The `<div id="version"></div>` is gonna be replaced with the new content fetched via Ajax. While it is still loading, I would like to add an image loader beside the `View changes` in `places/revisions.html.erb`. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you trigger it using jQuery.

in your view, you can place a div which containing an image besides "View changes".

```
<div id="version"><!-- #version used for ajax -->
  Click "View changes" to see the diff. 
  <div class="image"></div><!-- it should be hidden first. -->
</div>

<a href="#" class="diff">View Changes</a>
```

and give two events to your AJAX trigger.

```
$('a.diff').click(function(){
   $.ajax({url: 'your url', 
        data: 'your params', 
        beforeSend: function() {
           $('div.image').show();
        }, 
        complete: function() {
           $('div.image').hide();
        }});

});
```

Comment: I am not sure what the url: or data: should be in my code. How can I find that out?

Comment: The url is your url what you want to send the ajax request to, in this example, it is the original href of the link. The data is your params of the url, if your url has contained the full params, then you don't need it. Please read the api: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/